# TypeError: $(…).modal is not a function in yii1

Tags: ajax, yii1.x

I have a  button, when i clicked on it a modal popsup. Then i enter data and submit the form using ajax. After data is submitted i wanted the modal to close. This is what i tried (relevent code )

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'employee-task-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'afterValidate'=>'js:function(form,data,hasError){
                        if(!hasError){
                                $.ajax({
                                        "type":"POST",
                                        "url":"'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('employeetasks/create','ajax')).'",
                                        "data":form.serialize(),
                                        "success":function(){
                                        toastr.success("Saved successfully.", "Success");
                                         $("#ajaxModal").modal("close");     
                                        // $("#ajaxModal").modal("hide");

                                        },

                                        });
                                }
                        }'
        ),
)); 


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
jQuery("body").on("click", ".popup", function (e)
{
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#ajaxModal").find(".modal-body").load(url + "?ajax=1", false, function (responseText, status, req)
    {
        if (status != "error") {
            $("#ajaxModal").modal({backdrop: "static", keyboard: true});
        }
        else
            toastr.error("Failed to load", "Loading failed");
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Data is geting saved ie,Ajax function is working so is toaster, but  modal is not closing and i get an error like Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function.

**EDIT**

I posted the same question in Yiiframework forum [Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69168-typeerror-%E2%80%A6modal-is-not-a-function/)

and they are saying that i cannot close a modal because **The modal() function doesn't exist in jQuery** Is it so?

I was able to hide the modal using this code `$("#ajaxModal").hide();`
but the background remains in grey colour(same colour as when modal poped up)

**EDIT**

hi, i tried like this

```
  $("#ajaxModal").hide();
               $("body").removeClass("modal-open");

               $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```

then i was to close the modal but next time when i click on the button modal is not pop ing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for error. I was calling modal before bootstrap.min.js. That was the reason why i was getting a  `TypeError: $(…).modal is not a function`
Error.